# Image as background and paintComponent

Tags: java, swing, background, jpanel, paintcomponent

I am simply trying make a game for college that is a ball that player navigates with keyboard to get through maze. The only thing I am stuck on is my background is an image of  a maze, when I add the "ball" it repaints the background (defualt color, no image) when I comment out the paint and paint component, the maze background is back, but no ball of course.

I am a new to java and I have searched this and can't see a good soulition for the code I already have. is it setOpaque? isOpaque?.... is opaque even the right direction?

Once I get this... i totally understand using collision detection to detect collisions with the maze "wall"

Trying to figure this out, being new to java, can make a grown man cry.

main.java

```
public class Main{

public static void main (String[] args){

    //System.out.println("Start of the Game");

    GameFrame game1 = new GameFrame();
}
```

JavaGame.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;


public class GameFrame extends JFrame{        

private int frameWidth = 240, frameHeight =315;
    int x, y;
    private Image dbImage;
    private Graphics dbg;

//Below is the constructor        

public GameFrame(){          

        super("OperationMaze!");
        addKeyListener(new AL());
        setResizable(false);
        //setTitle("OperationMaze!2");
        //setSize(250, 302);
        setSize(frameWidth, frameHeight); //Set height and width
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);            


            //Because of opening file, there needs to be a try catch just incase there is an error opening.
            //Plus java won't let you unless you try catch.
    try{

                setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Documents and Settings/brando/My Documents/NetBeansProjects/GameFrame/src/maze.jpg")))));

    }   catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();                    
                }       


        //Show the frame


        setVisible(true);
        //setOpaque(false);    
        y = 35;
        x = 15;
}

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

       dbImage = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
       dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
       paintComponent(dbg);
       g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);           
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {                

        g.fillOval(x, y, 15, 15);
        //g.setOpaque(false);

        repaint();        
    }   

   // private void setOpaque(boolean b) {
   //     throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.

   // }

    public class AL extends KeyAdapter { 

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
            if(keyCode == e.VK_LEFT) {
                if(x <= 5)
                    x = 5;
                else 
                    x += -5;
            }
            if(keyCode == e.VK_RIGHT) {
                if(x >= 230)
                    x = 230;
                else
                    x += +5;
            } 
            if(keyCode == e.VK_UP) {
                if(y <= 23)
                    y=23;
                else
                    y += -5;
            } 
            if(keyCode == e.VK_DOWN) {
                if(y >= 277)
                    y = 277;
                else
                    y += +5;
            } 
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, lets's see what's going wrong here:

> when I add the "ball" it repaints the background (default color, no image)

In this scenario, when you are using your custom `paint` method, you don't call `super.paint(g)`, so the `JLabel` with the `Image` doesnt get drawn.

The `Image` that you *do* create is blank:

```
dbImage = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
```

(`Graphics` offers a [convenient overloaded method of drawImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29) that allows you to specify width & height, allowing you to avoid doing this.)

The result: no background image.

> when I comment out the paint and paint component, the maze background is back, but no ball of course.

Now `Swing` is calling the default `paint` implementation which ensures that all child components are drawn but now you're not calling your `fillOval` method, net result: background  `Image`, no ball.

*Where next:*

To allow Swing do the work of custom painting you need to *override* `paintComponent` rather than calling it directly. However this cannot be done in a top level container like `JFrame`. Sub-classing a `JComponent` and overriding `paintComponent` in that new component will allow Swing to call that method without you having to do it directly. Adding the `@Override` will allow the compiler to check that you *are* indeed overriding the method. As you're intending to paint the `Image`, you could simply load the `Image` and save the reference for use when you need to paint it:

```
dbImage = ImageIO.read(new File("MyImage.jpg"));
```

Then in your new `JComponent`-based class:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
   super.paintComponent(g);
   g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
   g.fillOval(x, y, 15, 15);
}
```